# Extracting data from a window in an application using c#

Tags: c#

I have an application which consists of a couple of windows along with
the main one. Please help me to extract some data present in one of these
windows using c#..

Comment: To clarify: The windows you want to get data from are not a part of your application, you want to write a program that captures data from some other application's window?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you're question properly, you have a popup window or dialog or some such, and you need to retrieve information from it after it has been closed (or some command is issued). There is no intrinsic way to do this with Windows Forms. You need to expose the data yourself:

```
class SomeForm: Form
{
    public string MyTextField
    {
        get { return txtMyField.Text; } // Gets the Text value of a control named txtMyField on this form
    }
}

// ...

var form = new SomeForm();
if (form.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.Ok)
{
    string data = form.MyTextField;
}
```